How to get TestNG Method Invocation Arguments
I know it's possible to get a TestNG method's parameters as described here: https://testng.org/parameters.html
However, I need to get the TestNG method's arguments.  Is this possible to get?
For comparison, I can get test method arguments in JUnit like so:  https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ReflectiveInvocationContext.html#getArguments()
Thanks for your help!

Oh wait...it turns out in TestNG methods the parameters are the arguments.  So, testResult.getParameters() works.
Sorry my mistake.  I've used JUnit previously and am new to TestNG.  I was confused by how JUnit and TestNG have different definitions of parameters and arguments.
